# Keycloak: updating master realm via Admin API

Tags: keycloak

I tried to edit the master realm of my keycloak standalone installation via the admin api interface. I already created a whole realm and everything works fine. If I now try to update the client roles inside the master realm the server responds with "No content" but the data is not changed. What do I wrong?

relative url:
`/auth/admin/realms/master/groups/654dc766-d307-4e44-9b6c-d53f16a2eedf`

body:

```
{
"id":"654dc766-d307-4e44-9b6c-d53f16a2eedf",
"name":"TECHNICAL",
"path":"/TECHNICAL",
"attributes":null,
"realmRoles":null,
"clientRoles":{
    "test-client-realm":[
        "manage-realm",
        "manage-users",
        "view-realm",
        "view-users"
    ]
},
"subGroups":[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

updating client goes via `PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{id}` and not as stated in your question. In your example you would update a group.

Comment: Yes, I need to update the group because it stores the client role mapping of this realm. Inside the client I can only create roles but cannot assign them to the realm.
In the Admin UI it would be like:
Select Realm -> Master -> Groups -> {GroupName} -> Role Mapping -> Select Client -> add Roles for this Group so User in this group have the rights for this client